# Get a URI for a RawContact photo in Android

Tags: android, photos, rawcontacts

I know I can get the URI of a contact's photo using:

```
Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(person, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

Is there a way to do the same for a RawContact?

I've tried:

```
Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);
Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(person, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

But it doesn't work...

The reason I need a URI instead of the actual blob is because the code is in an AppWidget and seems like there a very hard limit of a couple of megs when passing data from a widget to the launcher, so I need to use setImageViewUri and not setImageViewBitmap.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to get the RawContact photo? I'm also looking for a way to get it but to no success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878158/get-rawcontact-photo/21881333#21881333)

I also had the very same problem and after digging around and reading Android's source code I got it. It's probably to late by now (for you) but here it is anyway.

```
public InputStream getBitmapFromUri(String rawContactId) throws FileNotFoundException {

    final Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(rawContactId)), RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    final InputStream imageStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(photoUri);

    return imageStream;
}
```

Comment: Nice find!! :)
I've read a bit on ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto, seems like they only added this on API 14, so that might explain why I never found it digging through the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to directly access the 'data' table(ContactsContract.Data) to get the photo for raw contacts. The column 'data15' should store it.
Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY is the contact's primary photo path, but no such path is provided for raw contacts in default.

Comment: Thanks, but data15 is the photo blob itself, so I can't use setImageViewUri on it... can I somehow get the URI of that blob?

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying for `RawContacts` you can also add `RawContacts.CONTACT_ID` to the projection, then you can build the URI the same way:

```
long contactId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));
Uri person = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(person, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

Comment: Thanks @Guihji, but I need to access the RawContact's photo, not the selected primary for that contact. I need the raw's because on some devices Facebook synced photos aren't accessible to 3rd party apps, so I first try to get the primary, if I can't access it (means it's a FB photo), I try to get another photo from one of the Raw's.

Answer (score 0):

A year later and no real answer, I guess it can't be done.

I ended up using `setImageBitmap` instead of `setImageUri`, 
and used a scaling code for the bitmap to reduce memory consumption as much as possible (a loop that requests smaller and smaller sizes of the bitmap until the size is under a const limit).

this seemed to work well for almost all our users, some still complain about missing pics in the widget, but I'd say less then 2-3% of our users which is kinda acceptable.