# Get RawContact photo

Tags: android, contacts, rawcontacts

I know it is possible to get the contact's photo using something like:

```
public InputStream getContactPhotoInputStream() throws IOException {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(mContactId));
        InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(contentResolver, uri);

        return is;
}
```

But now I need to access all RawContact's photo (the one that have one). But I can't.
From [ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.html) documentation, the photo is saved as a file and the thumbnail is saved as a `Blob` in the `Data` table. I can get the thumbnail photo with simple query to the database and retrieve the `Blob` but now I need the original size photo and I can't find a way to get it. I can't find any info on android documentation neither on google.

I tried this method (adapted from the save photo file) to get the photo file but to no success.

```
public InputStream getRawContactPhotoInputStream() throws IOException
    {
        Uri rawContactPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(mRawContactId)),
                RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

        AssetFileDescriptor fd = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(rawContactPhotoUri, "rw");
        InputStream is = fd.createInputStream();

        fd.close();

        return is;

    }
```

I get this on LogCat:

```
02-18 23:44:27.195: D/PhotoRestlet(8984): Representation1 size < 1
02-18 23:44:27.207: W/System.err(8984): 2014-02-18  23:44:27    10.17.1.54  -   -   8080    GET /contact/photo/6    -   200 -   0   35  http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36   -
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984): Unable to read the entity
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984): java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984):     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.readImpl(FileChannelImpl.java:315)
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984):     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:287)
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.io.ReadableChunkingChannel.read(ReadableChunkingChannel.java:137)
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.fill(Buffer.java:395)
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.OutboundWay.onFill(OutboundWay.java:388)
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:601)
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.Way.processIoBuffer(Way.java:503)
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.OutboundWay.processIoBuffer(OutboundWay.java:463)
02-18 23:44:27.226: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.Way.onSelected(Way.java:456)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration.onSelected(SelectionRegistration.java:325)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.Connection.onSelected(Connection.java:617)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration.onSelected(SelectionRegistration.java:325)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.onSelected(ConnectionController.java:219)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerConnectionController.onSelected(ServerConnectionController.java:99)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.selectKeys(ConnectionController.java:308)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.ConnectionController.doRun(ConnectionController.java:171)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at org.restlet.engine.connector.Controller.run(Controller.java:159)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:123)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:144)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.readImpl(FileChannelImpl.java:303)
02-18 23:44:27.230: W/System.err(8984):     ... 21 more
02-18 23:44:27.250: D/PhotoRestlet(8984): Representation1 size < 1
02-18 23:44:27.250: W/System.err(8984): 2014-02-18  23:44:27    10.17.1.54  -   -   8080    GET /contact/photo/6    -   1001    -   0   17  http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36   -
02-18 23:44:27.269: D/PhotoRestlet(8984): Representation1 size < 1
02-18 23:44:27.273: W/System.err(8984): 2014-02-18  23:44:27    10.17.1.54  -   -   8080    GET /contact/photo/6    -   1001    -   0   19  http://10.17.1.72:8080  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36   -
02-18 23:44:27.308: D/skia(1925): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
02-18 23:44:27.308: D/skia(1925): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
02-18 23:44:27.316: D/skia(1925): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging around, looking android's source code exhaustively, I found a way to get the image from a raw contact.

Using Android's native code to get it, I did my own solution (my problem was getting the raw contact's image URI, I couldn't find a way to get it). So from here [public static boolean savePhotoFromUriToUr](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4_r1/com/android/contacts/util/ContactPhotoUtils.java#ContactPhotoUtils.savePhotoFromUriToUri%28android.content.Context,android.net.Uri,android.net.Uri,boolean%29) I did this:

```
public InputStream getBitmapFromUri(String rawContactId) throws FileNotFoundException {

        final Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(rawContactId)), RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        final InputStream imageStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(photoUri);

        return imageStream;
}
```

So here it is, how to get the raw contact's photo.